# NgIf hide parent and show child

Tags: angular

I have a case i want to achieve and I do not know if it is possible. Basically I have something like this.

```
<div *ngIf = false>
...long code
    <div ngIf = true>
       ...long code
    </div>
</div>
```

The Idea is to only show the child components and hide all the parents for some conditions.
How can I achieve something like this.

Comment: no, that's not possible even without Angular

Comment: I see. The only issue is that the code is very long. I can simply copy paste the child below the parent and show hide as the condition. I thought if I can keep the code only one place would be better.

Comment: maybe you don't need to hide the parent, just the contents of it, something like this `<div class="parent"><div class=" parent content" ng-if>...</div><div ng-if class="child">`

Answer (score 0):

As @Maximus suggested, you can hide portions of the parent's content instead of the parent itself.
So something like this

```
<div> <!-- the parent -->
        <div *ngIf ="!someVariable">  <!-- contents of the parent -->
        ...long code
    <div ngIf ="someVariable"> <!-- the child -->
       ...long code
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are going this route, I think the better way is to just remove the parent-child relationship and just have 2 divs.

```
     <div *ngIf ="!someVariable">  <!-- contents of the parent -->
        ...long code
     </div>
    <div ngIf ="someVariable"> <!-- the child -->
       ...long code
    </div>
```

I think it is much simpler. Hope this helps.

Comment: It drives us towards code duplicity. Is there any better way (I mean angular directive)?

Comment: @MCFreddie777 can you elaborate more on your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this by using ng-template outlets

```html
<parent *ngIf="condition else child">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="child"></ng-container>
</parent>
<ng-template #child>
    ...child contents
</ng-template>
```